# Asp.Net gridview customization

Tags: asp.net, gridview

If you go to http://ifdefined.com/btnet/bugs.aspx you will see a long list of sample data in an asp.net gridview control. What I need to do is something similar. I need to implement the filtering system by placing dropdown controls with dynamic values on the headers and then filter the record according to them.

If you look carefully they are filtering the data based on multiple drodown selections as well.

Kindly help me out. Any kind of input is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Are you sure that page uses an Asp.Net gridview? The html output sure doesn't look like it.

Comment: I think he would like to do the same action but with a gridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

1. set the dropdownlists to
   `autoPostback=true`
2. Reload the
   data in the Dropdownlist
   selectionChnaged event.  Give the
   gridview a new dataset with the
   applied filter and call `DataBind()`
3. Place the griview + Dropdownlist into an UpdatePanel for ajax functionality

Comment: Wrapping the whole process in a ScriptManager tag is a great way to make the page more dynamic and "ajaxify" it.