# refresh Gridview using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdown menu that affects my select statement for a gridview. The grid is updating correctly based on selection if I refresh the page.

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataSource4.SelectParameters["userIdSelected"].DefaultValue = userNameDropDown.SelectedItem.Value;
    //update grid here
    }
```

How do I see the updated grid when my drop down list changes?

Comment: It sounds like you need to set your DropDownList's AutoPostback attribute to true, but it is unclear.

Comment: I feel silly, but that worked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asp.Net gridview customization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829220/asp-net-gridview-customization)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set your DropDownList's AutoPostback attribute to true. I suggest you use also an UpdatePanel.

You can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx) to learn more about UpdatePanel.